# C++ "pause: not found" without system("pause")

Tags: c++, linux, csv

I'm working on a little script to practice using the boost libraries.

Using [these](https://gist.github.com/joshgrib/e90acdc405616af235f3) headers/namespaces, this is my main function:

```
int main()
{
ifstream inNew("../../Downloads/altr20141106test.csv");
accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean, tag::variance > > acc;
accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean, tag::variance > > acc2;
accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean, tag::variance > > acc3;
if (inNew){
    string line;
    while (getline(inNew, line,',')){
        cout << line << endl;
        acc(::atof(line.c_str()));
        getline(inNew, line,','); //
        cout << line << endl;
        acc2(::atof(line.c_str()));
        getline(inNew, line);
        cout << line << endl;
        acc3(::atof(line.c_str()));
    }
}
inNew.close();
return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with `g++ FILENAME` then `./a.out`.

This code works fine on my friends computer (Visual Studio 2012, Windows) but on mine (Command line, sublime text, Linux) I'm getting the error `sh: 1: pause: not found`. My friend had `system("pause");` in his, which I took out as that doesn't work for Linux, but I'm still getting the error.

[This](https://gist.github.com/joshgrib/d970464b6f89efde9e78) is the csv file used in the code, just arbitrary numbers.

Anyone know why I would get an error for using pause when I'm not? I tried deleting `a.out` before recompiling again too.

Edit: This was sent out by a professor of mine for class to learn to use boost

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RSahu I'm prety sure I did, that's the code, cut down, working, and still producing the error. How can I make it more minimal complete or verifiable?

Comment: You need to include the code in the question, if its too much for that then its too large. Also don't see any `system("pause")` in that code... is it really the code for the question?

Comment: @ChrisBeck Ok question edited so the code is in there now, and that's exactly the problem, there is no `system("pause");` but it's giving me an error like there is

Comment: @JoshGribbon: Try to reproduce it in an online build environment like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ or http://ideone.com/ , I guess that you can't and the problem is that your build system is broken somehow. No one really can help you with that. If you are getting errors about symbols that don't actually appear in your program, it means that you aren't compiling the code you think you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running the code you think you are.

If you removed `system("pause")` and it still errors on that, you're simply running the old binary. Try removing that binary (or all binaries) and checking where the compiled binarie(s) turn up.

Comment: I tried a new directory, same problem, so I made a new file and typed it up again and now it doesn't get the error anymore. It's not at all working but it fixed the problem. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @JoshGribbon This is the reason why we ask you to create a minimal working example. The steps you walk through while doing so often cause you to find the problem yourself.